# AttributeError at /delete/1/ Generic detail view DeleteTodo must be called with either an object pk or a slug in the URLconf

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

I'm starting with Django, and i wanna create simple projects to test my skills. First is the simple todo list. I've found a problem during trying to create 'delete task' functionality on my project.

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from .models import Task
from .forms import TaskForm
from django.views.generic import DeleteView



def index(request):
    return render(request, 'todoxd_app/index.html')

def todo(request):
    objekt = Task.objects.all()
    context = {'objekt': objekt}
    return render(request, 'todoxd_app/todo.html', context)

def new_todo(request):
    if request.method != 'POST':
        form = TaskForm()
    else:
        form = TaskForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('todoxd_app/new_todo')

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'todoxd_app/new_todo.html', context)

class DeleteTodo(DeleteView):
    model = Task
    template_name = 'registration/delete_todo.html'\
```

```
urls.py
```

```
    from django.urls import path, include
    from .views import DeleteTodo
    from . import views
    
    
    app_name = 'todoxd_app'
    
    urlpatterns = [
        path('', views.index, name='index'),
        path('todo/', views.todo, name='todo'),
        path('new_todo/', views.new_todo, name='new_todo'),
        path('delete/<post_pk>/', DeleteTodo.as_view() ,name='delete_todo'),
    ]
```

delete_todo.html

```
        
    
    
        
        Title
    
    
         {% extends 'todoxd_app/base.html' %}
    
        {% block content %}
    
            
                {% csrf_token %}
    
    
                DELETE TASK
    
            
    
        {% endblock content %}
```

```
   

     from django.db import models
    
    class Task(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        description = models.TextField()
        date_added = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
        date_end_of_task = models.CharField(max_length=20)
        progress = models.BooleanField()
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.name
```

I would be grateful for help (:

Answer (score 0):

for deleting task you have to specify django which task you want to delete and for that you have to call an id or slug field which has to be uniques only for that task then you can delete task here is the way and i am using id here

```
def DeleteTodo(request, id):
    task = Task.objects.filter(id=id)
    task.delete()
    return render(request, 'registration/delete_todo.html')
```

in your html in href tag by which you want to allow user delete that task

```
<a href="{% url 'todoxd_app:delete_todo' id=task.id %}">Delete It</a>
```

and last in your url

```
path('<int:id>/delete', views.DeleteTodo, name='delete_todo'),
```

and now you can delete it

Comment: In url file, Views shouldnt be write   DeleteTodo.as_view() , if i have class-based view?

Comment: so you want to use class based view for the samething instead of function based view but both will work fine

Answer (score 0):

By default, detail views like `DeleteView` will look for the primary key in the url with the kwarg `pk` as explained in the [**`docs`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.pk_url_kwarg). So if you want to support using `post_pk` in your view, set that as the value in `pk_url_kwarg`:

```
class DeleteTodo(DeleteView):
    model = Task
    template_name = 'registration/delete_todo.html'
    pk_url_kwarg = 'post_pk'
```

Or a simpler way to fix this is change your url config to use `pk` instead:

```
path('delete/<int:pk>/', DeleteTodo.as_view(), name='delete_todo'),
```